# How to get last date from all dates for each student

Tags: php, mysql, date, date-sorting

I'm making query, which takes all  driving courses students had in some period and compares if student has driven all courses that he paid for. 
   I need to get for each student, their last drives startTime, for example - "Martin paid for 5 courses and now in july he had his last course. So did 20 other people. And now administrator needs to make report, in that report, last course is last day of fulfillment.

My PHP

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors","1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include("../../config.php");
$down= array();
$xx=0;
$query = "SELECT   jq.stud_id as id,
                   jq.Subject as name,
                   jq.StartTime as endtime,
                   (select SUM(drives_count) FROM jqcalendar WHERE   
                   stud_id=jq.stud_id and 
                   Description IN(5, 6, 14, 17, 18, 34)) as drive_count 
                   FROM jqcalendar jq
                   LEFT JOIN csn_bills b ON jq.stud_id=b.student_id
                   LEFT JOIN csn_bills_details bd ON b.id=bd.bill_id
                   where jq.StartTime > '".$_GET['from']."' AND 
                   jq.StartTime < '".$_GET['till']."' AND 
                   jq.Description IN(5, 6, 14, 17, 18, 34) AND 
                   b.student_id=jq.stud_id";
$get_drives= $db->fetch_array($query);

foreach($get_drives as $key ) {
    $quant=0;
    $bill_id= $db->fetch_array("SELECT cb.id as bill_id, cb.payment_type, cb.bill_doc_date, bd.quant as quant  FROM csn_bills cb
                                LEFT JOIN csn_bills_details bd ON cb.id=bd.bill_id WHERE student_id=".$key['id']." AND cb.atskaite=0");
    if(isset($bill_id)){
        foreach ($bill_id as $key2 ) {
            if($key2['payment_type']==1){
                $quant=$quant+$key2['quant'];
                $down[$xx]['id']=$key['id'];
                $down[$xx]['name']=$key['name'];
                $down[$xx]['drive_count']=$key['drive_count'];
                $down[$xx]['bill_id']=$key2['bill_id'];
                $down[$xx]['bill_date']=$key2['bill_doc_date'];
                $down[$xx]['endtime']=$key['endtime'];
                $down[$xx]['payment_type']=$key2['payment_type'];
                $down[$xx]['quant']=$quant;

            }
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "No report";
    }   
    $xx++;
 }

//echo json_encode($get_drives);
echo json_encode($down);
//echo json_encode($bill_id);
?>
```